# how to make three divs line up horizontal instead of vertical. wordpress

Tags: wordpress, html

I was working on some code in the CSS and when I went to look at the changes I had made, the divs were now lined up vertically, instead of horizontal. I am trying to make the three divs, in the footer, to line up left to right. I am not sure why the div containers move at all.

Any help would be awesome!

Here is the link to my test page - http://jayclarkephotography.com/

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `float:left` to each `div` tags' style and decrease their width so they can line up together. Else they will be aligned vertically.

Answer (score 1):

in your css you will need to add the following:

```
.footer_box{float:left; width:352px;}
```

the width specified above is your container div width (1056px) divided by 3. you may need to reduce this number if you have padding etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
#container {height: 100%; width:100%; font-size:0;}
#left, #middle, #right {display: inline-block;zoom: 1; vertical-align:top;font-size: 12px;}
#left{width: 25%; background: blue;}
#middle{width: 50%; background: green;}
#right{width: 25%; background: yellow;}
```

Place three div(left, middle, right) in container div and apply above style on all.
    hope this help you :)